# How can I ground this charger

Tags: macbook-pro, power, charger

This charger came with my MacBbook Pro which I bought from India.

[image]

The other end is connected to the magsafe adapter's ground pin. What do I need to insert here?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime, I can't help but feel we're missing some context around this question. Why is it you need to insert *anything* at all? Is there something about how/where you're using this you haven't clarified?

Comment: That's not even an Indian plug, it's an EU combination of types E & F. India uses type D. You either need a travel adaptor or clip the plug & replace it with your own country's type… but you didn't tell us what country you're in. Ref: https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/

Comment: I live in India

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an international travel adaptor, from the European plug type, specifically plug types E & F, to an Indian plug, type D.

See [WorldStandards - Plug & socket types](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/) for further information.

If you are a competent electrician, you could snip off the existing 'foreign' plug & change it for a domestic… I would weigh that against not recognising the plug type & solution & say "Don't do that yourself!"

You can get travel adaptors in any airport & usually at stores that cater to travellers, e.g. luggage stores, or generally in tourist areas.

*Note:* Apple power supplies are multi-voltage, so you don't need to make any allowances for a potential supply difference between the two. [India & the EU are both 240v anyway, but just for sake of completeness.]